# Remove specific lines inside a range with sed

Tags: scripting, sed

I'm trying to remove a block inside a pair of matching patterns using sed. Given a block like:

```
                            <span 
class="fxlbc-t1-x-x-172">M<span 
class="small-caps">A</span><span 
class="small-caps">R</span><span 
class="small-caps">S</span></span>
                               <span 
class="fxlbc-t1-x-x-248">R<span 
class="small-caps">A</span><span 
class="small-caps">I</span><span 
class="small-caps">S</span><span 
class="small-caps">O</span><span 
class="small-caps">N</span></span>
```

I need to remove the block:

```
                            <span 
class="fxlbc-t1-x-x-172">M<span 
class="small-caps">A</span><span 
class="small-caps">R</span><span 
class="small-caps">S</span></span>
```

I'm trying to do that in sed. The first problem I'm hitting when using the `N` selector, is the problem of odd vs even lines. I've fixed this by doing this:

```
sed -i 'N
 /.*<span \nclass="fxlbc-t1-x-x-172".*/,/.*class="fxlbc-t1-x-x-248".*/ {
   /.*fxlbc-t1-x-x-172.*/d
   }' test.html

# Add an empty line
sed -i '1i\ ' test.html

sed -i 'N
 /.*<span \nclass="fxlbc-t1-x-x-172".*/,/.*class="fxlbc-t1-x-x-248".*/ {
   /.*fxlbc-t1-x-x-172.*/d,
   /.*
   }' test.html
```

I'm pretty sure there must be an easier way of doing it, and then I'm stuck with how to properly remove the other lines of the block (without removing the `fxlbc-t1-x-x-248` `span` line). Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was given the answer to my problem by a colleague:

```
sed -i ':a ; $! { N ; ba } ; $s/\(<span\( \|\n\|\t\)\+class="fxlbc-t1-x-x-172">[^4]\+\)\(<span\( \|\n\|\t\)\+class="fxlbc-t1-x-x-248">\)/\3/g' test.html
```

It puts the whole file in a buffer, and then does a standard search and replace on the buffered string. I reckon it's very ugly though, but it does the trick.